# Detect if the user draws a specified shape

Tags: android, android-studio, draw, shapes

I am creating an app where a shape (circle, square, triangle...) pops up on the screen. The user then has to trace the shape shown on the screen in order to move on. The only documentation I have found is on simple gestures, but nothing on complex shape drawing gesture. Is anyone aware of any android constructs that achieve this? Any help is very appreciated!

so far I have looked into android canvas and the ability for the user to draw shapes. However, I cannot find a method that will match the drawn shape to a pattern. I also looked into gesture detection, but found that it was only used to detect basic gestures such as swipes

-Kelton

Comment: @Nullarbor so far I have looked into android canvas and the ability for the user to draw shapes. However, I cannot find a method that will match the drawn shape to a pattern. I also looked into gesture detection, but found that it was only used to detect basic gestures such as swipes.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this [Tracking Movement](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html). It should work when you store data from movement and then compare it to your actual object